# How can I enable write 18 on a MikTeX installation

Tags: miktex, shell-escape

I have tried my best, but don't seem to get this one right. How do I enable shell escape in MikTeX?

Why XeLaTeX comes with a default for shell escape but not LaTeX?

Comment: It might be useful to say what you've tried: for example, what suggests to you that there is a difference between `latex` and `xelatex`?

Comment: Usually just use `-shell-escape` (or whatever MikTeX has for it as a command line option)

Comment: @MartinScharrer Either `--shell-escape` or `--enable-write18`.

Comment: @JosephWright with pdfLaTeX direct compilation of pst is possible with `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}. With pdfLaTeX I get the error "shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I do everything on windows via TeXworks, would prefer to stay within the editor while compiling.

Comment: Did you try to add the option in the `preferences` dialog, as described [here](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/AdvancedTypesettingTools). So you can add the option `-shell-escape` or `-enable-write18` to a new command that you are defining. I remember reading somewhere that the `-shell-escape` option is not safe (maybe someone can elaborate on this), but I'm not sure and can't find that statement. So, maybe, putting it by default is not a good idea.

Answer (score 24):

A similar question came up recently in a German [user forum](http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=72270). The user found the answer in the end with help of [this link](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/write18)

You can enable write18 by writing

```
initexmf --edit-config-file=miktex\config\pdflatex.ini
```

in DOS. You can get to the DOS window by hitting the windows Start button, click on "run" and write "cmd" (without the quotes obviously, this might also be slightly different for win7, I think there you can write cmd right in the search line that comes up after hitting the start button).

It might as well also work to do Start->run and then paste the above line right into this little run window (see below)

the `pdflatex.ini` should open in an editor and you can enter

```
EnableWrite18=t
```

save and close the file. Now it should be permanently enabled with pdflatex.

Another way is to pass `-enable-write18` to pdflatex. This can usually be done in the editor of your choice. For example in TeXnicCenter it looks something like:

Path of the compiler:

`C:\...\pdflatex.exe` (this is set already)

Arguments passed to the compiler

```
-interaction=nonstopmode -enable-write18 %tm
```

[image]

### **Update:**

To do this on WinEdt, do the following:

1. Go to `Options` and click on `Execution Modes` (See image below)

   [image]
2. Enter `--enable-write18` under the `pdflatex` Accessories under `switches` as shown in the diagram below.

   [image: execution modes interface]

Comment: This hack also works when using pdf2latex under Linux.

Comment: With the pass-through option to pdflatex (with TeXStudio) I had to run the editor as Administrator under Windows 10 for this to work.

Comment: Enabling this globally as default is terrible advice. There is a reason this is not the default. You should at least include a clear warning about the risks of doing this.

Comment: I tried this with my winedt and miktex setup and still can't get a basic gnuplot to work... Might there be something else stopping miktex and gnuplot from interacting properly?

Comment: @JohnD maybe try running the editor as admin as a test

Answer (score 7):

In Windows + TexWorks, when using `texify`, I have to add:

```
--tex-option=--shell-escape
```

To the tool configuration window:

[image: TexWorks options for --shell-escape on Windows]

Source: [How to do shell-escape in TeXWorks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187276/how-to-do-shell-escape-in-texworks#comment433613_187276)

Comment: As of 2021, you probably want the more secure `--shell-restricted`, and to add the executable you want to run to the configuration file.