# Student t-distribution with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw a Student's t-distribution with five degrees of freedom using TikZ, then another with 10 degrees of freedom, etc.

In the program I am working in the degrees of freedom will be a random number from 1 to 20, so I need a t-distribution for the degrees of freedom assigned by Perl randomization.

Comment: Please show some attempt you've made in achieving this and specify what you're struggling with. The point of this Q&A site is to solve specific problems, not to have other people do your work.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: A related animation (for a normal distribution), might help someone someday (I realize it's off topic, but it's only a comment): https://gist.github.com/ptoche/81326c6811bdf4253ef309c46c356464#file-pgfplots-animation-normal-distribution-tex

Answer (score 14):

This is a [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)/`gnuplot` solution.

For `\addplot gnuplot {…}` to work you need to have a working installation of `gnuplot` on your machine and have to call `pdflatex` with write18 enabled [(i.e. `--shell-escape` or `--enable-write18`)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/how-can-i-enable-write-18-on-a-miktex-installation).
How `pgfplots` and `gnuplot` interact can be studied in the [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) manual in subsection 4.2.5 “Computing Coordinates With Mathematical Expressions (gnuplot)”.

There are two `foreach` loops in this code. One that loops over `tikzpicture` and gives you one plot per picture, the other one loops over `\addplot` so that you will get *one* picture  with nineteen plots.

*Edit:* Apparently `gnuplot` sees `/2` as an integer rather than a floating point division.
The function is therefore:

```
gamma((\n+1)/2.)/(sqrt(\n*pi)*gamma(\n/2.))*((1+(x*x)/\n)^(-(\n+1)/2.))% or
gamma((\n+1)/2.)/(sqrt(\n*pi)*gamma(\n/2.))/((1+(x*x)/\n)^((\n+1)/2.))% or
gamma(.5*(\n+1))/(sqrt(\n*pi)*gamma(.5*\n))*((1+(x*x)/\n)^(-.5*(\n+1)))% or
gamma(.5*(\n+1))/(sqrt(\n*pi)*gamma(.5*\n))/((1+(x*x)/\n)^(.5*(\n+1)))%
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\basefunc{%
    gamma(.5*(\n+1))/(sqrt(\n*pi)*gamma(.5*\n))*((1+x^2/\n)^(-.5*(\n+1)))%
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,...,20}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0,
            ymax=.41,
        ]
            \addplot gnuplot [
                smooth,
                no marks,
                domain={-6:+6},
                ]{\basefunc};
            \legend{$n = \n$}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=0,
        ymax=.41,
    ]
    \foreach \n in {2,...,20}{
        \addplot gnuplot [
            very thin,
            smooth,
            no marks,
            domain={-6:+6},
            ]{\basefunc};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Animated output of the first `tikzpicture`s

[image: Output of the first animated tikzpicture]

### Output of the second `tikzpicture`

[image: Output of the second tikzpicture]

Answer (score 10):

Run it with `xelatex` or the sequence `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=1.25cm,yunit=10cm}
\begin{pspicture*}(-6,-0.1)(6,0.5)
\psaxes[Dy=0.1]{->}(0,0)(-5,0)(5.5,0.5)
\psTDist[linewidth=1pt,plotpoints=100,linecolor=red,
  fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!50,opacity=0.4, nue=3]{-5}{5}
\rput(3,0.3){$\nu=3$}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

And for the values nue = 1,2,5,1000:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=10cm}
\begin{pspicture*}(-6,-0.1)(6,0.5)
\psaxes[Dy=0.1]{->}(0,0)(-5,0)(5.5,0.5)
\psset{linewidth=1pt,plotpoints=100}
\psTDist[linecolor=red,nue=1]{-5}{5}
\psTDist[linecolor=green,nue=2]{-5}{5}
\psTDist[linecolor=blue,nue=5]{-5}{5}
\psTDist[linestyle=dashed,nue=1000]{-5}{5}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: click on the image: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery/Gallery  You need to convert the pdf width `convert` into an animated gif

Answer (score 9):

If you want to plot the function without using gnuplot, you can define the approximation for the gamma function using `declare function` and use that for plotting the t-distribution.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={gamma(\z)=
    2.506628274631*sqrt(1/\z)+ 0.20888568*(1/\z)^(1.5)+ 0.00870357*(1/\z)^(2.5)- (174.2106599*(1/\z)^(3.5))/25920- (715.6423511*(1/\z)^(4.5))/1244160)*exp((-ln(1/\z)-1)*\z;},
    declare function={student(\x,\n)= gamma((\n+1)/2.)/(sqrt(\n*pi) *gamma(\n/2.)) *((1+(\x*\x)/\n)^(-(\n+1)/2.));}
]

\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
    enlargelimits=upper,
    samples=50
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,5,100}{
    \addplot [thick, smooth, domain=-6:6] {student(x,#1)} node [pos=0.5, anchor=mid west, xshift=2em, append after command={(\tikzlastnode.west) edge [thin, gray] +(-2em,0)}] {$n=#1$};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is also possible with tkz-fct and gnuplot. It's possible to use a scope to keep the color red local for the curve. Without the scope I need to to indicate the black color to draw the axes. I used the function given by Qrrbrbirlbel. I fixed `\n` but it's possible to use `\foreach`.

**Update**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,font=\small]
 \tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-0,ymax=.5,ystep=.05] 
 \tkzGrid
\foreach \n in {2,4,...,20} {% 
\pgfmathsetmacro\col{3*\n+20}
     \tkzFct[color=red!\col!blue,domain=-5:5]{%
         gamma((\n+1)/2.)/(sqrt(\n*pi)*gamma(\n/2.))*(1+x**2./\n)**(-(\n+1)/2.)}  
} 
 \def\n{10} 
 \pgfmathsetmacro\col{3*\n+20} 
   \tkzFct[color=red!\col!blue,domain=-5:5]{%
       gamma((\n+1)/2.)/(sqrt(\n*pi)*gamma(\n/2.))*(1+x**2./\n)**(-(\n+1)/2.)}
   \tkzDrawArea[opacity=.3,color=red!30,domain = -6:6]   
 \tkzAxeXY[color=black]     
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As edited to my answer and [commented by the OP](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80345/student-t-distribution-with-tikz/80404#comment172897_80404) gnuplot needs `/2.` instead of `/2`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes you are right. I used your function without checking its validity. Sorry !

Answer (score 4):

To complete the overkill of the number of solution here a version with `gnuplottex`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color solid]
    unset key
    set samples 1000
    set format '$%g$'
    set xrange [-6:6]
    set yrange [0:0.41]
    f(n,x) = gamma(.5*(n+1))/(sqrt(n*pi)*gamma(.5*n))*((1+x**2/n)**(-.5*(n+1)))
    plot for[i=1:20] f(i,x)
\end{gnuplot}

\end{document}
```

> [image]