# Installing pgfplots package on Mac OS Lion

Tags: pgfplots, installing, mac

I was wondering if I can get help on installation of `pgfplots` package on Mac OS Lion for LaTeX. I have downloaded a zip file from [pgfplots download link](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/) but don't really know how to install it. I also checked the PDF file in the downloaded zip file; couldn't find a clear instruction on installing the package.

Comment: For starters, you linked to [`pgf.sourceforge.net`](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/) which is the homepage of PGF/TikZ. Maybe you were looking for [`pgfplots.sourceforge.net`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/)? Which TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: Assuming you are using the MacTeX distribution (which you should be unless you have very good reasons not to) `pgfplots` should already be installed. See [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10256/2693).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel  Ok, So I am using LaTeX (updated the question). Thank you for the hint. It helped. I have no problem compiling the examples given in the mentioned website. However, I use a lot of probability distribution graphs in my document and would like to be able to plot them inside LaTeX isntead of inserting them from an external file. Is there anyway to, for example, plot Normal CDF or PDF using pgfplots?

Comment: @AlanMunn: You are right; it was a silly mistake from my side

Comment: Ok. Then we'll close this question as too localised.  Thanks for responding to the comment.

Comment: You can draw distributions using tikz and there are many questions here explaining how to do that. See for example how to draw a [chi-square distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40908/14), a [t-distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80345/14), and a [bivariate normal distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31708/14). If you search the site you can find other examples.

Comment: @Vivi: Thank you so much. This is very helpful. I have hard time using gnuplot in latex code. I asked a question at [installing gnuplot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87297/help-with-installing-gnuplot-in-mactex-and-using-it-with-latex). I really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: @NNik Sorry, I have no experience with gnuplot... I am sure someone is going to help you :) Good luck!