# Why is binomial probability calculation wrong in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, calculations

During [my investigation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449570/164314) of [this nice question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449569/164314) by @Sentient, I found a rather bizarre problem: Given the binomial parameters `n=15` and `p=0.7`, @Sentient’s code produces some probability values *greater than two*! This can be illustrated with other parameters as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=0.88,
    declare function={binom(\x,\n,\p)=\n!/(\x!*(\n-\x)!)*\p^\x*(1-\p)^(\n-\x);},
    declare function={normd(\x,\n,\p)=binom(\x*\n,\n,\p);},
    declare function={normaldensity(\x,\n,\p)=exp(-\n*(\x-\p)^2/(2*\p*(1-\p)))/sqrt(2*pi*\n*\p*(1-\p));}
]
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[cyan, domain=0:1, samples=26, smooth]{normd(x, 25, 0.72)};
    \addplot[orange, domain=0:1, smooth]{normaldensity(x, 25, 0.72)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=0.88,
    declare function={binom(\x,\n,\p)=\n!/(\x!*(\n-\x)!)*\p^\x*(1-\p)^(\n-\x);},
    declare function={normd(\x,\n,\p)=binom(\x*\n,\n,\p);},
    declare function={normaldensity(\x,\n,\p)=exp(-\n*(\x-\p)^2/(2*\p*(1-\p)))/sqrt(2*pi*\n*\p*(1-\p));}
]
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[cyan, domain=0:1, samples=27, smooth]{normd(x, 26, 0.72)};
    \addplot[orange, domain=0:1, smooth]{normaldensity(x, 26, 0.72)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: wrong binomial]

On the left, I set `n=25` and `p=0.72`; On the right, I set `n=26` and `p=0.72`. The orange curves are the Gaussian approximations generated by the function `normaldensity` (the formula can be found in [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449570/164314)), *which should be close to the cyan curves (generated by `normd`, “normalized binomial”) in both graphs*.

However, the calculations of binomial probabilities by `normd` are way off on the right, producing probability values bigger than 3! On the contrary, the calculations on the left are perfectly fine. I’m sure @marmot has already noticed this problem when writing [this excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449572/164314), because the gamma function approach produces curves *very different* from @Sentient’s (but are very close to the Gaussian curves).

My question is: Why does this calculation error occur (*but only sometimes*, e.g., `n = 23, 24 or 26` but not for `n = 25`), and how can I fix it?

Comment: Probably overflow issues.  Factorials are huge numbers and you are dividing a huge number by another huge number which will result in a large numerical error due to finite precision.

Comment: To substantiate @HenriMenke statement, try `\addplot[red,only marks,samples at={0,1,...,26}](x/26,{binom(x, 26, 0.72)});`. This should produce marks on top of the cyan plot, but it does not. This seems to suggest that there some issues with these large numbers. I had a very similar problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445017/121799), where I found that it helps to set the brackets differently, i.e. instead of plotting `(huge/large)*small` you may set the brackets in such a way that you arrive at `(not so huge/large)*((not so huge)*small) `.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the binomial distribution is not a continuous function.  It is in fact discrete: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes. The Gaussian approximation is a different version of the Central Limit Theorem mentioned in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449570/164314) to the mentioned post. Basically, you *CAN* use the *continuous* Gaussian density to approximated the discrete distribution of the sum of independent identically distributed [lattice random variables](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatticeDistribution.html). And changing parameters in my answer is precisely because `n=15, p=0.7` do not work.

Comment: And if you plot `\addplot[red,only marks,samples at={0,1,...,26}](x/26,{binom(x, 26, 0.72)});` instead, the issue does not arise. But no, I was not aware of the fact  that the problem arises here. @HenriMenke This is true. In principle, one should only plot marks at discrete values. Nevertheless it is possible to define a continuous variant using the Gamma function. That is a standard trick in physics. It is actually fun to play with the analytic properties of these beasts.

Comment: @HenriMenke And if it is overflow, then why is `n=25` working but not for `n=24` or `n=23`? As I said, it breaks down, but only sometimes and it is rather unpredictable.

Comment: @RuixiZhang It always breaks down because factorial of a real number is bogus.  PGFplots will just happiliy truncate all over the place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot [my own take](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446027/164314) on how TeX stores real numbers (how embarrassing!). Long story short, in the original function `normd` by @Sentient, `\x*\n` is passed to be put into factorial calculations. Even after I told `PGFplots` to use

```
\x = 0, 1/\n, 2/\n, ... , \n/\n
```

it is very likely that the resulting `\x*\n`’s are *none* of the integers from `1` to `n-1`. This leads to ridiculous results of the factorials, and then leads to probabilities greater than one.

So, a clear fix is to use integer `\x`, then normalizing the x-coordinate as @marmot tried in the comments. This method at least guarantees the factorials are somewhat accurate. The problem of overflow is another beast which I don’t want to bring up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\section*{The correct left is by luck}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=0.88,
    declare function={binom(\x,\n,\p)=\n!/(\x!*(\n-\x)!)*\p^\x*(1-\p)^(\n-\x);},
    declare function={normd(\x,\n,\p)=binom(\x*\n,\n,\p);},
    declare function={normaldensity(\x,\n,\p)=exp(-\n*(\x-\p)^2/(2*\p*(1-\p)))/sqrt(2*pi*\n*\p*(1-\p));}
]
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[cyan, domain=0:1, samples=26, smooth]{normd(x, 25, 0.72)};
    \addplot[orange, domain=0:1, smooth]{normaldensity(x, 25, 0.72)};
    \addplot[red,only marks,samples at={0,1,...,25}](x/25,{binom(x, 25, 0.72)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=0.88,
    declare function={binom(\x,\n,\p)=\n!/(\x!*(\n-\x)!)*\p^\x*(1-\p)^(\n-\x);},
    declare function={normd(\x,\n,\p)=binom(\x*\n,\n,\p);},
    declare function={normaldensity(\x,\n,\p)=exp(-\n*(\x-\p)^2/(2*\p*(1-\p)))/sqrt(2*pi*\n*\p*(1-\p));}
]
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[cyan, domain=0:1, samples=27, smooth]{normd(x, 26, 0.72)};
    \addplot[orange, domain=0:1, smooth]{normaldensity(x, 26, 0.72)};
    \addplot[red,only marks,samples at={0,1,...,26}](x/26,{binom(x, 26, 0.72)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\section*{One should use integers for factorial calculations}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=0.88,
    declare function={binom(\x,\n,\p)=\n!/(\x!*(\n-\x)!)*\p^\x*(1-\p)^(\n-\x);},
    declare function={normd(\x,\n,\p)=binom(\x*\n,\n,\p);},
    declare function={normaldensity(\x,\n,\p)=exp(-\n*(\x-\p)^2/(2*\p*(1-\p)))/sqrt(2*pi*\n*\p*(1-\p));}
]
\begin{axis}
%    \addplot[cyan, domain=0:1, samples=26, smooth]{normd(x, 25, 0.72)};
    \addplot[orange, domain=0:1, smooth]{normaldensity(x, 25, 0.72)};
    \addplot[red,only marks,samples at={0,1,...,25}](x/25,{binom(x, 25, 0.72)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=0.88,
    declare function={binom(\x,\n,\p)=\n!/(\x!*(\n-\x)!)*\p^\x*(1-\p)^(\n-\x);},
    declare function={normd(\x,\n,\p)=binom(\x*\n,\n,\p);},
    declare function={normaldensity(\x,\n,\p)=exp(-\n*(\x-\p)^2/(2*\p*(1-\p)))/sqrt(2*pi*\n*\p*(1-\p));}
]
\begin{axis}
%    \addplot[cyan, domain=0:1, samples=27, smooth]{normd(x, 26, 0.72)};
    \addplot[orange, domain=0:1, smooth]{normaldensity(x, 26, 0.72)};
    \addplot[red,only marks,samples at={0,1,...,26}](x/26,{binom(x, 26, 0.72)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: correct binomial probabilities]

As someone who works with probabilities a lot, I barely used `PGFplots` to *program* my distribution functions. I found it easier (and more accurate) to use data generated by statistics software to draw in `PGFplots`.