# Coordinate calculation with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I need to draw some plots with vertical lines from the x axis to the function. For example, I defined the `gauss(x)` function for the normal distribution and I drew this plot, with a vertical line from (1.96, 0) to (1,96, gauss(1.96)) and the corresponding simmetric line:

```
\documentclass{book}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}
  }
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
  \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
      domain=-4:4, samples=61, smooth,
      clip=false,
      enlargelimits=upper
    ]
    % normal distribution PDF
    \addplot [thick] {gauss(x,0,1)};
    % right vertical line
    \pgfmathparse{gauss(+1.96,0,1)};
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgftempa\pgfmathresult;
    \node[coordinate] (a) at (axis cs:+1.96,\pgftempa) {};
    \draw (axis cs:+1.96,0) -- (a);
    % left vertial line
    \pgfmathparse{gauss(-1.96,0,1)};
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgftempb\pgfmathresult;
    \node[coordinate] (b) at (axis cs:-1.96,\pgftempb) {};
    \draw (axis cs:-1.96,0) -- (b);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(code above may contain some math errors as it's a MWE from a longer code, just ignore them)

I know, after searching on this forum, that I can't use `gauss(x)`directly after `axis cs`, but when I have to draw many lines the code becomes huge, and unreadable. Also, I'd like to avoid using many variables \pgftemp*.

Is there an easier way to evaluate a function which does not require three lines of code? For example, would it be possible to define a new command `\evaluatefunction(x)` and write `axis cs: 1.96,\evaluatefunction(1.96)` or  `\evaluatefunction{gauss(1.96,0,1)}`? I already tried this but it does not work:

```
\newcommand{\evaluatefunction}[1]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1};
  \pgfmathsetmacro\pgftempa\pgfmathresult;
}
\node[coordinate] (a) at (axis cs:+1.96,\evaluatefunction{gauss(1.96,0,1)}) {};
```

Compilation of this code does not end, and I have to stop it, so I can't even get an error log.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.  It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem - at the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using...

Comment: Done, I also forgot to enclose the tikz code in axis environment

Comment: Why the extra parenthesis in `\pgfmathparse{#1)};`? Should be `\pgfmathparse{#1};`?

Comment: @Bordaigorl yes, I missed it after replacing `gauss(#1,0,1)` with `#1`, however it's still not working

Comment: Sorry for the many mistakes and missing parts in the code above, I extracted it from a big picture in a document with a huge preamble divided in many files

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406449, maybe can help

Comment: @Zarko in this solution coordinates are still computed before being used, but I'm looking for a way to compute them on the fly (`axis cs: 1.96,<compute here gauss(1.96)>`)

Comment: why? does this has some benefits? sorry, i don't see any :-)

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, did you try what happens when you draw the vertical lines in the OP's MWE with the usual syntax, i.e. with `\draw (+1.96,0) -- (1.96,{gauss(+1.96,0,1)});` ? Your code does not help in this regard, I am afraid.  If you want so see benefits, just look at my code below, where one can just put `\draw (1.96,0) -- (1.96,{gauss(1.96,0,1)});` and no mysterious shifts happen.

Comment: @marmot, thank you for explanation. i will check your solution again. it seems that i overlooked this.

Comment: @Zarko Maybe you want to have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279229/121799). Ironically, it was never really clarified *why* `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` is "bad" but it (sort of) was agreed on that the syntax I was familiar with id "better". I *guess* it has to do with the `fpu` library.

Comment: @marmot, thank you very much for this link. i wasn't aware for this question. i also prefer solutions with syntax which i'm familiar :-)

Comment: @Zarko I was also not aware of this question before you showed up in this thread. ;-) BTW, I checked whether or not switching fpu off helps, and the answer is no. So most likely it is something else.

Comment: @marmot I read somewhere that TikZ does some calculations for placing nodes in the axis c.s. and the use of \pgfmathparse (the PGF engine loaded by TikZ) interferes with those calculations: (1) If you put `\pgfmathparse{}\pgfmathresult` after `axis cs` you just get errors; (2) if you write `\pgfmathparse{};\node at (axis cs: 0, \pgfmathresult) {}` you get the result of calculations made by `\node` command, that override your parsed expression.
I guess that the native PGF used in your code is independent from the engine loaded by TikZ and maybe that's why your solution work and mine does not.

Comment: @Taekwondavide I don't know since there are no (obvious) nodes involved in `\draw (1.96,0) -- (1.96,{gauss(1.96,0,1)});` but this also did not work properly with your original syntax. Even the point `(1.96,0)` got shifted and there was a large universal shift of the hole plot. There are a lot of things going on with `\nullfont` and so on and I do not understand those at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not so much familiar with the way you declare a function. However, if I use the way I am familiar with, there is no problem.

```
  \documentclass{book}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{pgfplots} 
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
  \tikzset{declare function={gauss(\x,\y,\z)=
  1/(\z*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\y)^2)/(2*\z^2));}}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
  \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
      domain=-4:4, samples=61, smooth,
      clip=false,
      enlargelimits=upper
    ]
    % normal distribution PDF
    \addplot [thick] {gauss(x,0,1)};
    \draw (1.96,0) -- (1.96,{gauss(1.96,0,1)});
    \draw (-1.96,0) -- (-1.96,{gauss(1.96,0,1)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same result can be obtained with an even more pgfplots like notation:

```
  \documentclass{book}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{pgfplots} 
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
  \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[declare function={gauss(\x,\y,\z)=
  1/(\z*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\y)^2)/(2*\z^2));},%
      domain=-4:4, samples=61, smooth,
      clip=false,
      enlargelimits=upper
    ]
    % normal distribution PDF
    \addplot [thick] {gauss(x,0,1)};
    \draw (1.96,0) -- (1.96,{gauss(1.96,0,1)});
    \draw (-1.96,0) -- (-1.96,{gauss(1.96,0,1)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` cannot be found in the pgfplots manual. However, on p. 544 the manual warns us that it automatically switches on `fpu`. This might be where be big overall and the small relative shifts come from, but I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you! This should be good for me, I'm trying to understand the difference between the two ways of declaring functions before accepting the answer

Comment: @Taekwondavide The difference is that `declare function` can be found in the pgfplots manual, meaning that it is fully supported, whereas `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` can't be found there. See page 544 of the pgfplots manual.

Comment: `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` is part of TikZ` (or, at least, it's documented in TikZ&PGF manual). I just wonder if there is any difference in how the computation is executed, such as variable size and computationa load

Comment: @Taekwondavide See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279229/121799) for an earlier discussion of the same issues... I guess one may now delve into the codes of Ti*k*Z and pgfplots or just accept as an empirical fact that the `declare function` syntax is better...

Comment: I take a better look to TikZ manual, looks like `\pgfmathparse` loads the mathematical engine of PGF in TikZ, while your solution is _native_ PGF. I guess that I would have had to use `\pgfmathparse` only if I hadn't used `pgfplot` package too.

Comment: @Taekwondavide `\tikzset{declare function={gauss(\x,\y,\z)=
  1/(\z*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\y)^2)/(2*\z^2));}}` works for both Ti*k*Z and pgfplots without problems (for me) so far.

Comment: yes, it works for me too, I mean that maybe it works in TikZ only if pgfplots is loaded too, and `\pgfmathparse` is needed otherwise. However, I'm using pgfplots so this is not an issue for me, and I'm going to use your solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to draw vertical lines from `y = 0` to the function value there is an even simpler way to achieve this using `ycomb`. Then, starting with [marmot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436328/95441) this reduces to following.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        /pgf/declare function={
            gauss(\x,\y,\z) = 1/(\z*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\y)^2)/(2*\z^2));
            mygauss = gauss(\x,0,1);
        }
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=-4:4,
        samples=61,
        smooth,
        enlargelimits=upper,
    ]
        \addplot [thick] {mygauss};
        % ----------------------------------
        % added/new stuff
        \addplot [
            ycomb,
            samples at={-1.96,1.96},
        ] {mygauss};
        % ----------------------------------
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you! In many cases I still need to create a `\node[coordinate]` for other purposes, as in marmot's solution, but in all other cases I'll use this one

Comment: Neither can I find a `node/coordinate` in marmot's answer, nor do I see a problem to add them to my answer ...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misspoke. I mean that this is a great solution, which let me avoid to create many unnecessary nodes as in my original code, however In some situations I did not explained here I still need to create the node and use `\draw`, otherwise I'll definitely use `ycomb`