# How to enable shell-escape in TeXworks?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, minted, texworks, shell-escape

I require use of the [`minted`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/minted) package of similar one which support Prolog syntax-highlighting.

Given that I use the [TeXworks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/) "IDE", how do I enable `shell-escape`?

[image: preferences]

Though I attempted—see above—I still receive this in my output:

```
! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.
```

Comment: Just found [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37509/7356)… is there a similar line I add for `-shell-escape`?

Comment: You should move `--shell-escape` before `$fullname` (just select the line and use the green arrows).

Comment: Note the two dashes in the argument (as per egreg's comment) for MiKTeX.

Comment: what is shell-scape for?

Comment: For running external programs. Escapes to the shell. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88741

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I have defined a new tool called `pdflatex+shellescape`:

[image]

And this is the console output if I run it on a file:

[image]

The log shows that the `--shell-escape` option has been activated. With MiKTeX you can call it `--enable-write18`, but since it understands also `--shell-escape` it's better to stick with the more general one.

Comment: Thanks; also I noticed after doing this it became impossible to compile the `.tex` file when it had spaces...

Comment: @AT I don't know in Windows, but on Unix systems  `"$fullname"` should work. In any case, better not using spaces in TeX file names.

Comment: If you use TeXworks on Windows, you might want to pass `--tex-option=--shell-escape` instead of just `--shell-escape`. Otherwise, you will get a cryptic error message: Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

Comment: @GuiTeK Sorry, but I've never used Windows in all my life.

Comment: Instead of making a new compiler, you can just add the `--shell-escape` command under the `-undump-xelatex` command right in the XeLaTeX configuration.

Comment: @AaronJPung The idea is that one wants to know precisely when running with `-shell-escape` active and not always.