# error during pdflatex; geometry-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found

Tags: graphics, pdftex, mactex

When running pdflatex the following errors occurred:"

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `geometry-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `force-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found."
```

Do I need to install a separate package or is there an other way to solve this?
Where do I find these files?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). you might be missing [`epstopdf'](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/epstopdf.pdf) package. are you on MiKTeX or TeXLive ?

Comment: Have a peek through a few of these to see if any help: [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+converted-to.pdf)

Comment: I am using MacTax

Comment: correction: MaCTeX

Comment: at Terminal, type `kpsewhich epstopdf.sty` to confirm the package presence and path. for automatic conversion from `.eps` to `.pdf` epstopdf.pl perlscript should be there. type this at terminal  `epstopdf -v` for its presence and confirm by running `epstopdf sample.eps` to get `sample.pdf` 
ping to the person using @username

Comment: Is the .eps file already present, or is does it have to be created beforehand? Sample.eps does not exist. "Cannot open sample.eps: No such file or directory" Where do I create this file?

Comment: @Olivier Open the terminal from where the .eps file exists, any .eps file is ok. I am not on Mac so i don't know exactly.

Comment: Initially I created a .tex file, but no .esp file was created. I now created a .esp file of the same code. I ran the command and the following error occurred:    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval-- (...)
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1160/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Comment: @Olivier try if you have `-shell-escape` [shell enabled](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82710/15717) in TeXshop assuming you are using this editor. also see at terminal `gs -v` for Ghostscript installation.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the errors are very likely the previous warnings:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `geometry.eps' not found on input line <xy>.
LaTeX Warning: File `force.eps' not found on input line <xy>.
```

Check the `.log` file for these warnings. Do the `.eps` files exists? If yes, where?

BTW, package `epstopdf` is loaded, because it is responsible for the suffix `-eps-converted-to.pdf`. Also `-shell-escape` should not be necessary at least in TeX Live, in its default settings, restricted shell escape is enabled, allowing `repstopdf` to run that is used for the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the following showed up in the logs:

```
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <img/emgt_logo.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2014-08-08 08:35:10
(epstopdf)                    size: 1072334 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <./emgt_logo-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=./emgt_logo-eps-converted-to.pdf img/emgt_logo.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 42.
runsystem(repstopdf --outfile=./emgt_logo-eps-converted-to.pdf img/emgt_logo.eps)...executed safely (allowed).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <./emgt_logo-eps-converted-to.pdf>.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File './emgt_logo-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
```

I tried the repstopdf and it failed to execute because the repstopdf was not installed, even though it executed safely and everything in the logs says OK.
I just installed it and everything was fine. There was No need to add any package in the tex file.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-font-utils
```