# Weird bodegraph output

Tags: texlive, texstudio, windows, gnuplot, bodegraph

I've tried to make a bodegraph with the bodegraph package and gnuplot. I'm using TexLive and TexStudio on a Windows 10 computer.

I get red axes and no graph, only the axes.

[image: Bodegraph]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    gnuplot def/.append style={prefix={}}, % Fixed the issue (prefix was 'gnuplot/\jobname/' before)
    ]
    \begin{scope}[xscale=10/3,yscale=10/110]
    \UnitedB
    \semilog{-1}{2}{-50}{60}

    \BodeAmp{-1:1.35}{\POAmpAsymp{4}{2.0}+\IntAmp{1}}

    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

TexStudio settings:
[image]

Comment: the display is correct on my pc with texworks

bodegraph uses gnuplot for plotting curves. are you sure you have properly configured pdflatex (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82699/how-to-enable-shell-escape-in-texworks)

Comment: I've done that, still get's the same output.

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but you don't need *both* `--shell-escape` and `-enable-write-18`, one is enough. You may need two dashes, I'm not really sure of the requirements.