# Change label color; bodegraph

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, bodegraph

Earlier question: [Weird bodegraph output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298829/weird-bodegraph-output)

I fixed the red color on the axis in the `.sty` file, but my `dB-` and `degree` label is still on the axis, and not above. Also, I want to change the `dB` labels color, how do I do that? I've tried modifying the `.sty` file, but I can't find the right parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Don't change the `.sty` file.

`bodegraph` sets up a series of styles that can be used to modify how things look, for example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    gnuplot def/.append style={prefix={}}, % Fixed the issue (prefix was 'gnuplot/\jobname/' before)
    ]
\begin{scope}[
    xscale=10/3,yscale=10/110,
    semilog lines/.style={blue},
    semilog lines 2/.style={blue,dotted},
    semilog label y/.style={above,black}]
\UnitedB
\semilog{-1}{2}{-50}{60}

\BodeAmp{-1:1.35}{\POAmpAsymp{4}{2.0}+\IntAmp{1}}

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to plot this function: H(s) = \frac{sRC}{1 + sRC}, but I get an graph from 10^3 rad/s to 10^9, but Matlab gives me 10^-9 to 10^-6. Bodecode: {-\IntAmp{1}+\POAmp{25e-6}{25e-6}} Any tips? The Bode documentation isn't very helpful. Is there any better way to plot bode graphs?

Comment: @wayl  That's a different question altogether, so I recommend making a new post. I don't even know what a Bode graph is, but in general you can plot a lot of stuff with the `pgfplots` package.