# pgfplots with gnuplot not showing graph for f(x) = 10517/x

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I'm using fixed axes.  pgfplots with gnuplots doesn't draw the line of the graph when I specify these axis dimensions:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ height=6cm, width=6cm,
        xmin=8, xmax=12,
        ymin=800,   ymax=1500]
\addplot gnuplot {10517/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The output I get is simply the axes with no graphed line.  For example, (9,1168.5) is a point on the line, so it should be visible here.  Any suggestions?  I'm using TeXworks as the editor.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you compile with `--shell-escape` enabled? (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82710/586) Edit: also, the default `domain` is `-5:5` I believe, so any points will be outside the axis limits you've set.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't know about the default domain.

Comment: It's the default for `pgfplots` at least, on second thought I'm not entirely sure what happens when `gnuplot` is used like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set up the `domain` as an optional argument of `gnuplot`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ height=6cm, width=6cm,
        xmin=8, xmax=12,
        ymin=800,   ymax=1500]
\addplot gnuplot [domain=8:12] {10517/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: @RebeccaSchley feel free to mark this answer as 'accepted' using the Green tick -- this rewards Schweinebacke with a further 15 reputation points for their time :)