# Problems with package pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot a sine wave, however, when I run it, the following error results:

> Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file 'main.sin.table' could
>    not be found. Maybe you need to enable the shell-escape feature? For pdflatex,
>    this is '>> pdflatex -shell-escape'. You can also invoke '>> gnuplot .gn
>   uplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file..

My MWE is the following:

```
 \documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
 \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,vector,physics,enumitem,mathtools}
 \usepackage{etoolbox}
 \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
 \usepackage{esvect}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{varwidth}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}
 \usetikzlibrary{through,calc,arrows}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$\sin(x)$
]
% invoke external gnuplot as
% calculator:
\addplot gnuplot[id=sin]{sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I already try solve it by following this answer: [How to enable shell-escape in TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82699/how-to-enable-shell-escape-in-texworks?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: do you have gnuplot installed?

Comment: Yes, I do. I just installed it.

Comment: You can plot a sine without gnuplot.

Comment: Can you tell me how @marmot?

Comment: Just remove `gnuplot` (I think). I also find it strange that you don't specify a domain. This should work: `\addplot[domain=0:6,samples=100][id=sin]{sin(deg(x))};
`.

Comment: Doesn't work @marmot :(

Comment: Probably your TeX distribution can't see gnuplot on the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment. Can you compile

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
 \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
 \usepackage{pgfplots}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$\sin(x)$
]
\addplot[domain=0:6,samples=100,id=sin]{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

On my TeXLive 2017 distribution it produces.

[image]

Notice that I have stripped off all unnecessary packages and libraries. (And I do not have vector.sty.)