# Epstopdf does not compile *.eps

Tags: errors, miktex, eps, winedt

I work in WinEdt + MikTex 2.8 and mostly compile the source through PdfTexify. In order to compile eps figures in this mode I used the package epstopdf, but recently it stopped working. This is quite strange, as I can't recall what I changed in the settings of WinEdt for example. Just to eliminate this latter possibility, I re-installed WinEdt and I'm pretty sure that the settings of WinEdt are now by default - e.g. the pdf reader is set to Acrobat (before re-installing it was Sumatra). However, the problem have not gone - here is the text:

```
[18]MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 8.60: **** Could not open the file ../plots/contourML-eps-converted-to.pdf .
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:cs1' on page 19 undefined on input line 1146.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `../plots/contourML-eps-converted-to.pdf' not 
found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1156 ...=true,width=5cm]{../plots/contourML.eps}

? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

Does anybody have an idea, hot to resolve the problem?

Comment: Check [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/how-can-i-enable-write-18-on-a-miktex-installation) out. It might be something related to enabling `shell escape`.

Comment: @AbdulhaqElhouderi: thanks for the suggestion - that indeed seems to be often the reason, but as appeared, not in my case: it didn't help. On the other hand, I have found, that if I store TeX auxiliary files in the same folder, there is no problem - only if I require them to be in a different folder there is a problem with epstopdf. Any idea, why can it be so?

Comment: I have experienced the same problem... I wondered if you found a solution. I have tried some solutions such as using --shell-escape option but it didnt work. In any case it could be that I am not configuring it correctly in winedt. I would highly appreciate any orientation about this problem.thanks arantxa

Comment: @arantxa: I'm using WinEdt and had this problem with it. I found that the problem disappears if I don't use a special folder for auxiliary files.

Answer (score 5):

WinEdt uses its own algorithm to store auxiliary files, that is, it saves all auxiliary files in a folder named `TeXAux` (unless you've changed it, it is customisable) and uses this folder as working folder.

Files placed in folders relative to your main `.tex` file are found thanks to the `TEXINPUTS` environmental variable to which your main folder is added.

The problem using relative paths containing things like `./` or `../` is that in these cases kpathsea simply checks if that file exists. Excerpt from the kpathsea documentation, section 5.1 (thanks to [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090) for this [full explanation](https://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?category=LaTeX&pr=latex%2F4470))

> Exception to all of the above: If the filename being searched for is absolute or explicitly
>   relative, i.e., starts with `/` or `./` or `../`, Kpathsea simply checks if that file exists.

So you have to go back one folder when you specify files, in your case:

```
\includegraphics{../../plots/contourML.eps}
```

instead of:

```
\includegraphics{../plots/contourML.eps}
```

This should work...

---

### **ADDENDUM**

Following Heiko's suggestions, I can say that the best way to make it work with WinEdt (both in MiKTeX and TeX Live) is to leave your `\includegraphics` lines as they were and add these lines to your preamble:

```
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}
\graphicspath{{../}}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following scenarios work for me in MiKteX 2.9:

```
% test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\epstopdfsetup{outdir=texaux/}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{plots/contourML.eps}
\end{document}
```

Files, relative to the current directory:

```
test.tex
plots\contourML.eps
texaux\
```

`pdflatex test` generates:

```
test.aux
test.log
test.pdf
plots\contourML-eps-converted-to.pdf
```

`pdflatex -output-directory=texaux test` generates:

```
plots\contourML-eps-converted-to.pdf
texaux\test.aux
texaux\test.log
texaux\test.pdf
```

### Option `outdir` of package `epstopdf`

Package `epstopdf` (that might be automatically loaded by `graphics.cfg`) supports an option `outdir`, where the directory for the converted files can be specified:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{outfile=texaux}
```

`pdflatex test` generates:

```
test.aux
test.log
test.pdf
texaux\contourML-eps-converted-to.pdf
```

`pdflatex -output-directory=texaux test` generates:

```
texaux\contourML-eps-converted-to.pdf
texaux\test.aux
texaux\test.log
texaux\test.pdf
```

Comment: I think Ilya was using WinEdt command `PDFTeXify` which already saves auxiliary files in `texaux` folder when it exists, without the need to specify the command-line switch `-output-directory=texaux`.

Comment: @karlkoeller I do not have WinEdt, thus I do not know, which options, which current directory,... WinEdt is using. At least the scenarios given in the answer provide some minimal models. With further information, they can be refined to get closer to the WinEdt case.

Comment: Your example works in WinEdt substituting `\epstopdfsetup{outdir=texaux/}` with both `\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}` or `\epstopdfsetup{outdir=../plots/}` because the working directory is `texaux`