# Autosegmental Representation with pst-asr

Tags: pstricks, linguistics, pst-asr

I am using Texmaker and MiKTeX to try and produce an autosegmental representation such as the one in this image:

[image: hwari]

The following code is given in John Frampton's pst-asr user's guide:

```
\asr[xgap=2em,syB=2.5em] hwari|
\@(1,sy){L}
    \-[xed=true,xedratio=.4](1,ts)\-[style=dotted](2,ts)
\@(2,sy){H}
    \-(2,sy)(2,ts)
\@(4,sy){L}
    \-(4,ts)
\endasr
```

No matter how I build the PDF document, the result is similar to this (i.e. not the autosegmental representation above):

[image: hwari2]

I am very new to this, so it is likely I am making a simple error. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

See also the full code of my document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pst-asr}
\begin{document}
\asr[xgap=2em,syB=2.5em] hwari|
\@(1,sy){L}
    \-[xed=true,xedratio=.4](1,ts)\-[style=dotted](2,ts)
\@(2,sy){H}
    \-(2,sy)(2,ts)
\@(4,sy){L}
    \-(4,ts)
\endasr
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to compile using `latex+dvips` rather than `pdflatex`.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158952/using-pstricks-with-texmaker for how to do this I. TeXMaker.

Comment: I configured the Quick Build Command to `LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf + View PDF` and then `LaTeX + dvips + View PS` but neither worked; both the PDF and DVI file had the malformed output as in the second image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pst-asr` documentation is somewhat difficult to read.  In order to use the shortcuts `\@` and `\-` you need to first execute the `\tiershortcuts` command. Following Stefano's comment, I've put this into a `\psset` command to apply it to each `asr` environment, which will ensure that the shortcuts don't interfere with any other packages' commands. Furthermore, the `style=dotted` should be `linestyle=dotted`.  So the complete document should be:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{pst-asr}
\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts}
\begin{document}
\asr[xgap=2em,syB=2.5em] hwari|
\@(1,sy){L}
    \-[xed=true,xedratio=.4](1,ts)\-[linestyle=dotted](2,ts)
\@(2,sy){H}
    \-(2,sy)(2,ts)
\@(4,sy){L}
    \-(4,ts)
\endasr
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Including the `\tiershortcuts` command has fixed the problem. Thank you, @Alan Munn.

Comment: I suggest to put `\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts}` which executes the command only inside the asr environments (and guarantees better compatibility with other packages).

Comment: @Stefano Thanks, Stefano, I've updated my answer to reflect your suggestion.