# PStricks and TexMaker/MikTex returns empty or strange PDF

Tags: pstricks, miktex, texmaker

I am trying out pstricks as it contains some really nifty packages for electric and magnetic fields.
However, I cannot get it to work quite yet.

My setup is as follows:

- TexMaker 4.4.1
- MiKTeX 2.9
- Windows 7

I have understood that there are some tricks to get pstricks to work (pun unintentional), and I think I am on the right track when I have configured TexMaker to QuickBuild in this manner:

*Latex+dvips+ps2pdf+viewpdf*

Then, pressing F1 to QuickBuild produces **.log, .dvi, .ps and .aux** but no PDF.

Pressing "PS-PDF" produces *Process exited with error(s)*, but no actual errors are listed and no log file created.

Pressing "DVI-PDF" in TexMaker produces a wall of errors and a PDF with a few letters:

[image]

[image]

I used the examplecode from the answer [to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158952/using-pstricks-with-texmaker):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\psscalebox{0.5 0.5} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-2.195)(7.73,2.195)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dotsize=0.07055cm 6.0]{-*}(3.2,1.805)(1.2,-0.595)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dotsize=0.07055cm 6.0]{-*}(3.2,1.805)(2.4,-1.395)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dotsize=0.07055cm 6.0]{-*}(3.2,1.805)(4.0,-1.395)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dotsize=0.07055cm 6.0]{*-*}(3.2,1.805)(5.6,-0.195)
\rput{66.6232}(2.6010673,-3.5480006){\psarc[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, linestyle=dashed, dash=0.17638889cm 0.10583334cm, dimen=outer](4.0,0.205){1.6}{208.56584}{270.0}}
\rput[bl](3.6,1.805){\Huge{$u$}}
\rput[bl](0.0,-1.395){\Large{ 1($\beta$)}}
\rput[bl](2.0,-2.195){\Large{ 2($\beta$)}}
\rput[bl](4.0,-2.195){\Large{ 3($\beta$)}}
\rput[bl](6.0,-0.595){\Large{ $n-1(\beta)$}}
\end{pspicture}
}
\end{center}
\caption{Graph of type - I matrix}\label{t1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### So what have I done wrong?

edit:
I have now added **-enable-write18** to the pdflatex command in TeXMaker and tried a different QuickBuild sequence:
*PdfLaTex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + View PDF*

The change is that the pstricks part of the code does not output anything, and no error messages.

All I get is **Figure 1: Graph of type - I matrix** on the top of an empty A4 page.

## Update: Pressing XeLaTeX twice in the quickbuild-menu works.:)

Comment: I have absolutely no problem with your code. The only things I changed are:  replacing the `latin1` option of `inputenc` with `utf8` (my editor, like all modern editors sets this as the default) and removing `\usepackage{pst-pdf}` since `auto-pst-pdf` is loaded. Also, I only made a simple compilation (just pdflatex).  Btw, it is better to play with `\psset{unit=…}` than using `\psscalebox` as the latter also scales text, arrowsize, &c.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I replaced 'latin1' with 'utf8' and removed 'pst-pdf'. Still the pstricks part does not render.

Comment: Hm, now I think I got it to work. Using xelatex :)

Comment: I didn't think it was related. I only wanted to warn you of (minor) modifications. Could you simply use  latex, *then* dvips, and see what you get with `gsview` (if you have ghostscript+gsview installed). I also tried the way `latex->dvi->dvipdf` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Fine! It would be good to know what happened the `latex->dvips->pstopdf` way, though. Perhaps a problem  of updating?

Comment: I downloaded and installed ghostscript and gsview, and it seems as if the .ps files are OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25750/discussion-between-bernard-and-fluxmodel).