# Problems with plotting planar functions with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried to plot [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/713873) graph using `tikz` and `pgfplots`. The code compiled just fine, but I got a peculiar result that I can't explain. My code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xmin=-6,xmax=6,ymin=-6,ymax=6, axis lines=center, axis equal]

\addplot[domain=-6:6,color=blue,samples=400]({sin(\x^2+\y^2)},{cos(\x*\y r)});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the riddle I was presented with.

[image]

The shape my code produced (a line, strangely enough) perplexes me. I truly have no idea what I did wrong. Is there any internal process at fault? Can you please modify my code in such a way that the desired plot will actually show up? I'd be grateful if you (kind users who already mastered `tikz` and `pgfplots`) would help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: probably better to give the direct link to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713873/very-interesting-graph rather than rely on google search

Comment: I'm assuming you mean http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713873/very-interesting-graph. You can't plot implicit functions directly in `pgfplots` like that. Try for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18359/plotting-an-implicit-function-using-pgfplots

Comment: I actually considered this, but at the end it isn't vital to the question. I will consider your suggestion again, though. Please help if you can. I'd like to observe the beauty of `pgfplots`.

Comment: Huh? What did you consider that you don't think is vital to the question? It is certainly vital that `pgfplots` cannot, as far as I know, plot implicit functions they way you're trying.

Comment: I considered putting the link directly to the Stack Exchange mathematics post and not simply to Google images not vital to my post, and NOT your information that states `pgfplots` can't do the desired work. I think you misunderstood me.

Comment: No, I didn't understand you at all. If you take the code in [Jake's answer to the question I mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18384/586), and replace the function in the `splot` line with `sin(x^2+y^2)-cos(x*y)`, then you get an approximation, though the precision isn't good.

Comment: I am grateful for your answer, though when I try to compile it after your demonstration I get this error: `! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file '"Poskusi (muahaha).pg
f-plot.table"' could not be found. Maybe you need to enable the shell-escape fe
ature? For pdflatex, this is '>> pdflatex -shell-escape'. You can also invoke '
>> gnuplot <file>.gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file..`. I tried changing `pdflatex` commands, just as `.log` file says, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this graph when I saw an introductory article on the small application [GrafEq](http://www.peda.com/grafeq/). The ideal behind is to compute the LHS and RHS using interval arithmetic. We cannot (at least it is pretty difficult to) do interval arithmetic in TeX. But we have the following for free

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading{interesting-1}{\pgfpoint{-25bp}{-25bp}}{\pgfpoint{25bp}{25bp}}{}{
    3 mul exch 3 mul exch % x y
    2 copy                % x y x y
    dup mul exch dup mul  % x y y² x²
    add sin               % x y sin(x²+y²)
    3 1 roll              % sin(x²+y²) x y
    mul cos               % sin(x²+y²) cos(xy)
    le                    % < or not <
    {0 0 0}{1 1 1}ifelse  % black or white
}
\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading{interesting-2}{\pgfpoint{-25bp}{-25bp}}{\pgfpoint{25bp}{25bp}}{}{
    3 mul exch 3 mul exch % x y
    2 copy                % x y x y
    dup mul exch dup mul  % x y y² x²
    add sin               % x y sin(x²+y²)
    3 1 roll              % sin(x²+y²) x y
    mul cos               % sin(x²+y²) cos(xy)
    sub dup mul           % (L-R)²
    .01 le                % <.01 or not <.01
    {0 0 0}{1 1 1}ifelse  % black or white
}

\begin{document}
    \tikz\path[shading=interesting-1](-10,-10)rectangle(10,10);
    \tikz\path[shading=interesting-2](-10,-10)rectangle(10,10);
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

## OR GNUPLOT

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
            \addplot3[domain=-40:40,samples=100,contour gnuplot={levels={0},labels=false}]
                {sin(x^2+y^2)-cos(x*y)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Choose what you love and love what you choose.

Comment: Um, thank you for your wonderful answer, I'm very grateful for it. Though I must say the result I got was not what you posted in your answer. Rather than getting a smooth plot, I have a bunch of pixels that *kind of* depict the general structure of the plot, but are utterly a mess. Can you help me with that? And also, I'd like to ask you to present an answer that can be attached to a mathematical paper (`axis`-like style). Thank you in advance.

Comment: @GregorPerčič I am afraid there is no short answer to your question. Functional shading is a very hard-core feature of PDF. If your PDF viewer cannot render this, you can only try with another viewer. Similar situation will happen if you submit this to a publisher. So a painless way is to attach a high-resolution raster image.

Comment: I checked my produced PDF and it produces the expected result! Thank you so much (you get a tick for your effort `:)`). Though I would like to know how to plot such a graph with `gnuplot` and `pgfplot`.

Comment: In the pgfplots manual page 151 it uses gnuplot to plot the contour of a given function (exp(0-x^2-y^2)). I think you should try that. (I do not have gnuplot installed; sorry.)

Comment: Could you provide a link? There are multiple `pgfplots` manuals.

Comment: There should be only one (official) one. On CTAN: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't able to find this one myself. I got only parts of the original one (300, sometimes 200 pages; abridged versions).

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful GNUPLOT solution. I can't compile it, as the following error shows up: `! Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{"Poskusi (muahaha)"_contourtmp0.tabl
e} could not be opened.` Help, please.

Comment: (1) check if you have gnuplot correctly installed. Try if you can compile a minimal example (such as mime or those on the manual) (2) Try to rename your folder and files without spaces.

Comment: No, I can't do anything of the above. I reinstalled `gnuplot`, changed `pdflatex` command to `escape-shell` (as recommended in documentation and this (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242132/plot-file-could-not-be-opened) answer), but to no effect.