# Commutative Diagram

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I need to put up a commutative diagram in my latex document but unfortunately I could not find any package which could do that.

I am putting up the diagram in an image below, please take a look.

[image]

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: See the tikz-cd package, do it as a 3x3 grid

Comment: Searching for latex commutative diagram found this line among others: http://www.jmilne.org/not/CDGuide06.pdf

Comment: If you could please mention page number that would be great. I could not find any such diagram in there. Thanks.

Comment: The `psmatrix` environment from  `pst-node` (`pstricks` family) is another solution.

Comment: You could also use the `XY-pic` package. See [tag:xy-pic] or http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/xypic/xyguide.pdf

Comment: `tikz-cd` is clearly your choice, if you are going to learn something new. Please do the beginning of that diagram and I will be happy to help you on any issue. There are already question on that circular arrow in `tikz-cd` around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with the `psmatrix` environment from `pst-node` (`pstricks` family)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts, amssymb}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{postscript}
  \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15, linewidth=0.6pt, dash=4pt 3pt, nodesep=2pt, labelsep=2pt, colsep=1cm, rowsep=1cm, emnode=R, npos=0.5}
  \begin{psmatrix}
    [name=DF] $ \mathcal{DF}_{\!H_a} $ & &[name=M]$ (\mathcal{M},\bar{\partial}) $\\[-1.5ex]
      & [name=PF] $ \mathcal{PF}_{\!\widetilde{H}_{a}} $ \\
      & $ \mathcal F $
      \everymath{\scriptstyle}
      \ncline[linestyle=dashed, nodesep=4pt]{DF}{M}\naput{$ \varphi $}
      \ncline[arrows=H->, nodesep=1pt,]{2,2}{1,1}\naput[ labelsep= -1pt]{$ i_\mathcal{D} $}%
      \ncline[arrows=H->, hookwidth=-2mm, nodesepA=-1pt]{2,2}{1,3}\nbput[labelsep= 0pt]{$ i_{\mkern-2mu\mathcal{M}} $}%
      \ncline{3,2}{1,1}\naput[labelsep=-2pt]{$ u_{\mathcal{D}} $ }
      \ncline{3,2}{1,3}\nbput{$ u_{\mkern-2mu\mathcal{M}} $}
      \nput[labelsep=18pt]{90}{PF}{\psarcn(0,0){0.25}{-40}{40}}
    \end{psmatrix}
      \everymath{\scriptstyle}
      \ncline[linestyle=dashed, nodesep=4pt]{DF}{M}^{$ \varphi $}
      \ncline[arrows=H->, hookwidth=1.5mm, nodesep=1pt,]{2,2}{1,1}\naput[ labelsep= -1pt]{$ i_\mathcal{D} $}%
      \ncline[arrows=H->, hookwidth=-1.5mm, nodesepA=-1pt, ]{2,2}{1,3}\nbput[labelsep= 0pt]{$ i_{\mkern-2mu\mathcal{M}} $}%
      \ncline{3,2}{1,1}\naput[labelsep=-2pt]{$ u_{\mathcal{D}} $ }
      \ncline{3,2}{1,3}\nbput{$ u_{\mkern-2mu\mathcal{M}} $}
      \nput[labelsep=18pt]{90}{PF}{\psarcn(0,0){0.25}{-40}{40}}
    \end{postscript} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you compile this with `pdflatex` (as should be) don't forget to add the `--enable-write18` switch when launching the compiler, if you're under MiKTeX, or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX).

Comment: Thanks again, I'll let you know if any other problem arises once I try this.

Comment: Hi @Bernard, I tried to add the switch using this link <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/how-can-i-enable-write-18-on-a-miktex-installation> but unfortunately, it doesn's recognise "intitexmf" command. Could you please tell me how to add this switch. I am using Texmaker 4.0.1 on windows 7 enterprise.

Comment: Which system and distribution do you have?

Comment: I am using Texmaker 4.0.1(compiled with Qt 5.0.1) on windows 7 enterprise (2009).

Comment: Goto `Options > Configure TeXMaker` The second line (about `pdflatex`) should contain the line `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode`. Replace it with `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  --enable-write18 %.tex` (if you're under MiKTeX) or `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  -shell-escape` (TeXLive, MacTeX). Perhaps also you should update TeXmaker (current version is 4.5).

Comment: Thank you very much , Now, I am not getting any errors but still this diagram doesn't appears on the pdf doc. At the end there is a warning which says pspicture No1. undefined.

Comment: @shzan: sorry, I forgot to mention that `pstricks` code has either to be compiled with `xelatex`, or with `pdflatex` , but in the latter case, the ci=$ompiler has to be launched with the `--enable-write18` switch, if you have `MiKTeX`, or `-shell-escape` for TeX LIve or MacTeX.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but again I don't how to do that. I tired to look up online but could not find anything. Sorry for being a newb.

Comment: What are your distribution, editor and operating system?

Comment: Texmaker 4.0.1(compiled with Qt 5.0.1) on windows 7 enterprise (2009) with Miktex 2.9

Comment: Go to `Options > Configure TeXmaker`. In the 2nd line, replace `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` with `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --enable-write18 %.tex`.

Comment: This is I have already done.

Comment: Well, you should be able to compile with pdflatex then.  Note I've just midfied a detail in the code to be sure.  What does the .log file say,exactly?

Comment: File `AGF-pics.pdf' not found and pspicture No. 1 undefined. Name of my file is "AGF" and I dont understand what is "AGF-pics.pdf". I have not used it anywhere.

Comment: Hi @Bernard, Could you please help me with this query.

Comment: Oh! yes, sorry, I had forgotten your problem was not completely solved. Let me explain: `pdflatex` can't manage `postscript` files (it does not incorporate a computation engine for postscript instructions), so it has to outsource them (whence the `--enable-write18` switch). During this process a postscript file is created,  then changed into a .pdf graphic file, and the latter is finally incorporated into the main .pdf file. Your compiler seems not to fing these intermediate files. You should try first to compile via `latex->dvips->pstopdf` to see if there's no other problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But there is no option for latex->dvips.

Comment: Goto `Options > Configure TeXmaker > Quick Build` and select the  3rd item.

Comment: Now there are so many errors like1.! Undefined control sequence. \@PackageInfoNoLine, 2.LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \@PackageInfoNoLine{e

Comment: Did you compile exactly the code I posted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37784/discussion-between-shzan-and-bernard).

Comment: yes, I did exactly what you have done.