# Circuit Drawing, \vco Causes Error

Tags: pstricks, pst-node, circuits

I want to draw a circuit using this code but it gives me errors
Where is the problem?.

```
   \documentclass[preview]{standalone}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{pst-circ}
        \usepackage{comment}
        \usepackage{cite}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

        % For ploting graphs
        \usepackage{amsfonts}
        \usepackage{amssymb}
        \usepackage{pst-plot}
        \usepackage{dashrule}
        \begin{document}
        \begin{figure}
                \begin{center}
               \begin{pspicture}(15,5)                                              
                    % AC Source
                    \pnode(0.5,2){A}
                    \pnode(0.5,0.5){B}          
                    \vco(B)(A){}
                    \newground(B)   


                    \pnode(0.5,3.5){A}                      
                    \pnode(2.5,3.5){B}
                    \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag,arrows=o](A)(B){$R_{1}$}
                    \pnode(4.5,3.5){AA}
                    \coil[dipolestyle=elektorcurved,arrows=-o](B)(AA){$L_{1}$}
                    \capacitor[parallel](AA)(A){$C$}


                    % Capacitor
                    \pnode(4.5,2){A}
                    \pnode(4.5,0.5){B}          
                    \capacitor(A)(B){$C_1$}
                    \newground(B)       

                    % Second Stage                      
                    \pnode(4.5,3.5){A}                      
                    \pnode(6.5,3.5){B}
                    \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag,arrows=o](A)(B){$R_{2}$}
                    \pnode(8.5,3.5){AA}
                    \coil[dipolestyle=elektorcurved,arrows=-o](B)(AA){$L_{2}$}  
                    \capacitor[parallel](AA)(A){$C$}                                                

                    % Capacitor
                    \pnode(8.5,2){A}
                    \pnode(8.5,0.5){B}          
                    \capacitor(A)(B){$C_2$}
                    \newground(B)

                    % Multiple Stages
                    \pnode(8.5,3.5){B}                  
                    \pnode(10.5,3.5){A}                             
                    \psline[linestyle=dashed,arrows=-o](B)(A)
                    \pnode(12.5,3.5){B}
                    \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag](A)(B){$R_{n}$}
                    \pnode(14.5,3.5){AA}
                    \coil[dipolestyle=elektorcurved,arrows=-o](B)(AA){$L_{n}$}
                    \capacitor[parallel](AA)(A){$C$}


                    \pnode(8.5,2){A}
                    \pnode(10.5,2){B}                               
                    \psline[linestyle=dashed,arrows=o-o](B)(A)          

                    \pnode(14,2.25){A}          
                    \pnode(13.75,3.25){B}
                    \pnode(13,4){C}                                 

                    % Capacitor
                    \pnode(14.5,2){A}
                    \pnode(14.5,0.5){B}         
                    \capacitor(A)(B){$C_n$}
                    \newground(B)       

                    % Mutual Impedances
                    \pnode(3.5,3.5){A}
                    \pnode(5.5,4.5){B}
                    \pnode(7.5,3.5){C}
                    \pscurve[linestyle=dashed]{-}(A)(B)(C)  
                    \pnode(5.5,4.75){B}
        %           \rput[cve](B){$R_{12}+j \omega L_{12}$} 
                    \rput[cve](B){$Z_{12}$} 

                    \pnode(8.5,4.5){B}
                    \pnode(13.5,3.5){C}
                    \pscurve[linestyle=dashed]{-}(A)(B)(C)  
                    \pnode(8,4.75){B}
        %           \rput[cve](B){$R_{1n}+j \omega L_{1n}  $}   
                    \rput[cve](B){$Z_{1n}  $}
                    \pnode(7.5,3.5){A}
                    \pnode(10.5,4.75){B}
                    \pnode(13.5,3.5){C}
                    \pscurve[linestyle=dashed]{-}(A)(B)(C)  
                    \pnode(10.5,5){B}
                    %\rput[cve](B){$R_{2n}+j \omega L_{2n}$}
                    \rput[cve](B){$Z_{2n}$} 
                \end{pspicture}
                \caption{ Simplified equivalent circuit of a transformer winding for frequency response analysis}   
                \label{Model_Circ_1}
                \end{center}        
            \end{figure}
        \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems come from the fact you use the `standalone` class, for which the notion of floats is meaningless. I removed everything that was incompatible or irrelevant, and it compiles fine. I added the `auto-pst-pdf` package to allow direct compilation with `pdflatex` (you have to launch the compiler with the `--enable-write18`switch under `MiKTeX`, `-shell-escape` with `TeX Live` or `MacTeX` to make it work):

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{pst-circ, auto-pst-pdf}
    \begin{document}

           \begin{pspicture}(15,5)
                % AC Source
                \pnode(0.5,2){A}
                \pnode(0.5,0.5){B}
                \vco(B)(A){}
                \newground(B)


                \pnode(0.5,3.5){A}
                \pnode(2.5,3.5){B}
                \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag,arrows=o](A)(B){$R_{1}$}
                \pnode(4.5,3.5){AA}
                \coil[dipolestyle=elektorcurved,arrows=-o](B)(AA){$L_{1}$}
                \capacitor[parallel](AA)(A){$C$}


                % Capacitor
                \pnode(4.5,2){A}
                \pnode(4.5,0.5){B}
                \capacitor(A)(B){$C_1$}
                \newground(B)

                % Second Stage
                \pnode(4.5,3.5){A}
                \pnode(6.5,3.5){B}
                \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag,arrows=o](A)(B){$R_{2}$}
                \pnode(8.5,3.5){AA}
                \coil[dipolestyle=elektorcurved,arrows=-o](B)(AA){$L_{2}$}
                \capacitor[parallel](AA)(A){$C$}

                % Capacitor
                \pnode(8.5,2){A}
                \pnode(8.5,0.5){B}
                \capacitor(A)(B){$C_2$}
                \newground(B)

                % Multiple Stages
                \pnode(8.5,3.5){B}
                \pnode(10.5,3.5){A}
                \psline[linestyle=dashed,arrows=-o](B)(A)
                \pnode(12.5,3.5){B}
                \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag](A)(B){$R_{n}$}
                \pnode(14.5,3.5){AA}
                \coil[dipolestyle=elektorcurved,arrows=-o](B)(AA){$L_{n}$}
                \capacitor[parallel](AA)(A){$C$}


                \pnode(8.5,2){A}
                \pnode(10.5,2){B}
                \psline[linestyle=dashed,arrows=o-o](B)(A)

                \pnode(14,2.25){A}
                \pnode(13.75,3.25){B}
                \pnode(13,4){C}

                % Capacitor
                \pnode(14.5,2){A}
                \pnode(14.5,0.5){B}
                \capacitor(A)(B){$C_n$}
                \newground(B)

                % Mutual Impedances
                \pnode(3.5,3.5){A}
                \pnode(5.5,4.5){B}
                \pnode(7.5,3.5){C}
                \pscurve[linestyle=dashed]{-}(A)(B)(C)
                \pnode(5.5,4.75){B}
    % \rput[cve](B){$R_{12}+j \omega L_{12}$}
                \rput[cve](B){$Z_{12}$}

                \pnode(8.5,4.5){B}
                \pnode(13.5,3.5){C}
                \pscurve[linestyle=dashed]{-}(A)(B)(C)
                \pnode(8,4.75){B}
    % \rput[cve](B){$R_{1n}+j \omega L_{1n} $}
                \rput[cve](B){$Z_{1n} $}
                \pnode(7.5,3.5){A}
                \pnode(10.5,4.75){B}
                \pnode(13.5,3.5){C}
                \pscurve[linestyle=dashed]{-}(A)(B)(C)
                \pnode(10.5,5){B}
                %\rput[cve](B){$R_{2n}+j \omega L_{2n}$}
                \rput[cve](B){$Z_{2n}$}
            \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Iam using winEdt, how can i launch the compiler with the --enable-write18switch under MiKTeX, -shell-escape with TeX Live or MacTeX?

Comment: Nevermind i used this link to enable it http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/how-can-i-enable-write-18-on-a-miktex-installation

Comment: luatex85.sty not found!

Comment: Are you under MiKTeX?

Comment: @Misaki: B.t.w., what does this code have to do with  luatex?

Comment: Yes iam under MikTex. i don't know this is the error i got.

Comment: @Misaki: Would you be compiling with `LuaLaTeX`? Anyway, you can install `luatex85` with MiKTeX Package Manager. It's not installed by default. That said, it has nothing to do with the code I posted.

Comment: Does it have the same name "luatex85" in Miktex? because i don't find it there.

Comment: Yes. You can install it with MiKTeX Package Manager (preferably in admin mode).

Answer (score 1):

Run the document with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% UTF8 is the default for xelatex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

% For ploting graphs
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{pspicture}(15.5,5.5)                                              
            % AC Source
            \pnodes(0.5,2){A}(0.5,0.5){B}          
            \vco(B)(A){}
            \newground(B)   

            \pnodes(0.5,3.5){A}(2.5,3.5){B}
            \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag,arrows=o](A)(B){$R_{1}$}
            \pnode(4.5,3.5){AA}
            \coil[dipolestyle=elektorcurved,arrows=-o](B)(AA){$L_{1}$}
            \capacitor[parallel](AA)(A){$C$}

            % Capacitor
            \pnodes(4.5,2){A}(4.5,0.5){B}          
            \capacitor(A)(B){$C_1$}
            \newground(B)       

            % Second Stage                      
            \pnodes(4.5,3.5){A}(6.5,3.5){B}
            \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag,arrows=o](A)(B){$R_{2}$}
            \pnode(8.5,3.5){AA}
            \coil[dipolestyle=elektorcurved,arrows=-o](B)(AA){$L_{2}$}  
            \capacitor[parallel](AA)(A){$C$}                                               

            % Capacitor
            \pnodes(8.5,2){A}(8.5,0.5){B}          
            \capacitor(A)(B){$C_2$}
            \newground(B)

            % Multiple Stages
            \pnodes(8.5,3.5){B}(10.5,3.5){A}                             
            \psline[linestyle=dashed,arrows=-o](B)(A)
            \pnode(12.5,3.5){B}
            \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag](A)(B){$R_{n}$}
            \pnode(14.5,3.5){AA}
            \coil[dipolestyle=elektorcurved,arrows=-o](B)(AA){$L_{n}$}
            \capacitor[parallel](AA)(A){$C$}


            \pnodes(8.5,2){A}(10.5,2){B}                               
            \psline[linestyle=dashed,arrows=o-o](B)(A)          

            \pnodes(14,2.25){A}(13.75,3.25){B}(13,4){C}                                 

            % Capacitor
            \pnodes(14.5,2){A}(14.5,0.5){B}         
            \capacitor(A)(B){$C_n$}
            \newground(B)       

            % Mutual Impedances
            \pnodes(3.5,3.5){A}(5.5,4.5){B}(7.5,3.5){C}
            \pscurve[linestyle=dashed]{-}(A)(B)(C)  
            \pnode(5.5,4.75){B}
            %           \rput[cve](B){$R_{12}+j \omega L_{12}$} 
            \rput[cve](B){$Z_{12}$} 

            \pnodes(8.5,4.5){B}(13.5,3.5){C}
            \pscurve[linestyle=dashed]{-}(A)(B)(C)  
            \pnode(8,4.75){B}
            %           \rput[cve](B){$R_{1n}+j \omega L_{1n}  $}   
            \rput[cve](B){$Z_{1n}  $}
            \pnodes(7.5,3.5){A}(10.5,4.75){B}(13.5,3.5){C}
            \pscurve[linestyle=dashed]{-}(A)(B)(C)  
            \pnode(10.5,5){B}
            %\rput[cve](B){$R_{2n}+j \omega L_{2n}$}
            \rput[cve](B){$Z_{2n}$} 
        \end{pspicture}
    \caption{ Simplified equivalent circuit of a transformer winding for frequency response analysis}\label{Model_Circ_1}        
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]