# A problem with currfile

Tags: luatex, currfile

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,german,14pt,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{currfile} 

\begin{document}


\ifcurrfiledir{folder1/folder2/Jungs}{Lieber}{Liebe}
\end{document}
```

I am struggling with the following problem:
In german language you talk to boy with the word "Lieber..." and you talk to a girl with the word "Liebe..." (for our english speaking friends: this means "Dear...". Now I would like to automate these words in a way that if the document is in the folder "folder1/folder2/Jungs" (Jungs means boy) then the word "Lieber" should be inserted and for the rest (i.e. the girls) the word "Liebe" should be used. For this purpose I tried the "currfile" package by Martin Scharrer with the code detailed above. But this doesn´t work since in both cases Lualatex returns "Liebe". Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Unrelated but don't do `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`  (`utf8x` has not been recommended for years, and in current releases it is defined to do nothing other than give a warning that it should not be used)

Comment: You don't say how you are running LaTeX, but the most obvious would be that you are already in `folder1/folder2/Jungs`, so there _is no relative folder_.

Comment: Off-topic: Option `14pt` for `scrbook` is obsolete. You should use `fontsize=14pt` instead as reported in the `log` file and shown in my answer. And if you have several options in the option list of `\documentclass` but only the main language as option for `babel`, it is recommended to use `main=…` when loading babel to avoid warnings. See again the warning in the `log` file of your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run LuaLaTeX from within the directory, you cannot test with `\ifcurrfiledir`, because the `\currfiledir` is relative to the current working directory. But you can (always) do a test with `\currfileabspath`, e.g.:

```latex
\documentclass[ngerman,german,fontsize=14pt,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile} 

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \JungsMaedelsSonstige { m m m }
  {
    \str_if_in:NnTF
      \currfileabspath
      { /Jungs/ }
      { #1 }
      {
        \str_if_in:NnTF
          \currfileabspath
          { /Maedels/ }
          { #2 }
          { #3 }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Dies ist Datei \currfileabspath{} für \JungsMaedelsSonstige{Jungs}{Mädels}{Sonstige}.

\end{document}
```

Note: Because of option `abspath` you have to run LaTeX with option `-recorder`. If the file above is named `jungsornot.tex` you would, e.g., have to run `pdflatex -recorder jungsornot.tex` instead of `pdflatex jungsornot.tex`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just another (maybe silly) question: I am using WinEdt (under Windows) as my editor. How do I start "pdflatex -recorder" from the editor or do I have to start from command line?

Comment: @mario1000 I'm not using WinEdt, but you should be able to add `-recorder` analogous to [enable shell-escape with WinEdt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37509/277964). If not, please ask another question.